# Hibernate - DataBase structure modelling

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have goal to make DB structure with table filesData, where will be stored information about uploaded files, and another tables for another objects.

Some objects can be linked to the filesData table, for example tables of the blog posts, news, etc. Each of these objects must have many linked files. For example, news post can have many pictures. In this case should be used "middle" tables for each type, ie, for news post shuold be 3 tables: NewsTable, NewsToFilesRelationsTable, filesData. It's standart way.

But now I want to build another way: I want to make setter method for settings Set of files for each object, what will consists of links to files, and annotate this method with custom meta annotation:

```
@MyFileAnnotation
public void setFiles(Set<FilesData> fd) {
        this.fd= fd;
}
```

But how to store this data? I don't want to make "middle" tables, with relation of the objects to the files records in the filesData table. Another variant - make one table filesDataRelation and store relations data in this table. In this case - what structure of this table must be? This table must have not only ID of the linked object's record, but also it must have row with data type of the object (it may be full name of the object's table).

How to build this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very simple.

I've made table framework_files and mapped it with JPA to object `FrameworkFiles implements java.io.Serializable`. This table have columns `linkedObjectID int` and `linkedObjectName varchar(250)`.

In another tables, for example - in table publicSitePortfolioWorks, that mapped to `public class PublicSitePortfolioWorks implements java.io.Serializable {` there are some columns and columns `id int (PK)` and `linkedObjectName varchar(250)`. Column `linkedObjectName` in all rows (records) has one (static?) value, what may be the same as the table name. For example:

ID | SomeCols | linkedObjectName

1  | blablabla| publicSitePortfolioWorks

2  | blablabla| publicSitePortfolioWorks

3  | blablabla| publicSitePortfolioWorks

Entity object PublicSitePortfolioWorks of the table publicSitePortfolioWorks linked to the child table as one-to-many with code

```
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "linkedObjectID", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "linkedObjectName", referencedColumnName = "linkedObjectName")
    })
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<FrameworkFiles> framework_files1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Where `name = "linkedObjectID"` - it's name of columns in child table, `referencedColumnName = "id"` - it's name of columns in current table, `name = "linkedObjectName"` - it's name of columns in child table, `referencedColumnName = "linkedObjectName"` - it's name of columns in child table.

This solution does not claim to be the most correct solution - it just works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use another table then I don't think there is a better way to do this. Maybe you want to consider using some NoSQL database? I recently have done that in my latest project. Some data are stored in Postres and the rest in MongoDB. There is a very good java library for Mongo integration. Check [spring-data-mongodb](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/)